# Android Activity Killed vs App Killed

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle

#### My Question

I'd like to call a function leaveGame() to leave a multi device game, when my app is killed. However, the game uses several activities to work. So, I can't call it in onStop, else the player will leaveGame() every time a new activity within the game launches.

**Is there a way to check if the app process itself is being killed?**

#### Current Solution

My current solution (very clunky) is to set a Boolean isCreated in all the activities that the GameActivity calls. (MissionActivity for eg)  I then check if it has been set in my onStop.(See Coordinating Activities [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html))

GameActivity

```
@Override
public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    if(MissionActivity.isCreated==null) leaveGame();
}
```

MissionActivity

```
public static Boolean isCreated;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mdgame);
    isCreated = true;
    //etc
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What about `onDestroy`? It will be called when Activity is killed/destroyed.

Comment: When the game is reset, I clear the stack and go back to gameSetupActivity. But I want the players to stay in the same game in the online database, and not be removed (as in leaveGame())

Comment: Well then you can clear the stack in `onBackPressed`, so when the user press/go back to the previous activity you can do what you want ie clear the stack.

Comment: You should think of all the ways the game may possibly be interrupted and do whatever you want when that happens.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to check if the app process itself is being killed?

No, sorry.

However, you can [use `ProcessLifecycleOwner`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ProcessLifecycleOwner.html) from the Architecture Components to find out when you no longer have any activities in the foreground.

Comment: Great suggestion but I'm new to this LifecycleOwner. Can't seem to import it? Or implement it? Mind if you provide a little code sample?

Comment: Found a [code example](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-androidarch/tree/v0.2/General/ProcessLifecycle) by @CommonsWare thanks